# Call function after setInterval

Tags: angular, setinterval

I have the submit button after clicking on which pop up appears. Pop up has a list of checkboxes that should be checked if backend response will be 1700 and after that pop us should be closed.
But calling the function that closes pop up  is called before that setInterval will be completed.

public sendApplication(): void {
    if (this.formService.isFormValid(this.formGroup)) {

```
    this.dialogProcessing
        = this.dialog.open(FoDialogBankVerificationComponent, {
        width: '500px',
        disableClose: true,
        data: this.checkBoxValues,
    });
    this.submit()
        .pipe(
            take(1))
        .subscribe(res => {
            if (res.id === 1700) {
                this.checkBoxValues.forEach((el, index) => {
                    setInterval(() => {
                        el.isChecked = true;
                    }, index * 1500);
                });
                this.status = res.id;
                this.dialogProcessing.close();
            }
        });
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you want to acomplish but looks like you are searching for `setTimeout(cb:Function, time: number)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

asynchronous programming, means parallel programming, where a unit of work runs separately from the other.

in your case , `this.status = res.id;` and `this.dialogProcessing.close();` will not wait till the end of **forEach** statement .

how to solve this => For exemple you can move the two affectations into **setInterval** bloc , and verify if its the last index to execute them

Something like this :

```
    if (res.id === 1700) {
                    this.checkBoxValues.forEach((el, index) => {
                        setInterval(() => {
                            el.isChecked = true;
                            if(index=== this.checkBoxValues.length - 1){
                               this.status = res.id;
                               this.dialogProcessing.close();
                            }
                        }, index * 1500);
                    });

    }
```